# Why is getline so inconsistent?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am at the computer lab and none of the tutors can figure out why my `getline` is not working correctly. It is not storing the information correctly (only stores 1 or 2 letters). Does anyone know why this is so?

```
void addMovie(Inventory movie[], int &count)
{
    string s;
    int i;

    cout << "Please enter the SKU " << endl;
    cin >> i;
    movie[count].sku = i;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the movie you wish to add " << endl;

    cin.ignore('\n');
    getline(cin, s, '\n');
    movie[count].title = s;

    count++;
}
```

Comment: As a note, you should probably be using some kind of standard container than a C-style array. You don't seem to be doing any bounds checking here.

Comment: You don't have to put in the `'\n'` on the `getline`, either. It's the default delimeter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::istream::ignore` (i.e. `cin.ignore()`)'s first argument is the number of characters to discard. The value of `'\n'` has an ASCII code of 10, so that `'\n'` is being implicitly converted to an integer (most likely 10, but it could differ if a different encoding is used - EBCDIC uses 21), and that's how many characters are being ignored, leaving a few left over.

What you actually want is to discard the maximum possible number until you find a newline:

```
#include <limits> //for numeric_limtis
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler have warned about this implicit conversion?

Comment: @muntoo, No, it's a common conversion well-defined by the standard. C++ doesn't differentiate `int` and `char` as separate types requiring user assurance to convert, as something like Java does, so both can be used interchangeably. You can see this on functions such as `tolower`, which takes and returns an `int`. That one comes from C, though, as I believe. The whole thing between ints and chars might come from C, but I can't remember. There's probably some good discussion on it somewhere on SO.

Comment: @muntoo, Just to point out an example, this is an excellent reason for `std::string` not having a constructor taking a single char. If you did `std::string str(10);` expecting a string with a length of 10, it would implicitly convert to a char and use that instead. It also works the other way around. Another thing I just remembered is that C's character literals had the type `int`, not `char`. I forget if C had `char` at all back then, but even having it, something like `tolower` would have to convert the character literal to a `char` first.

Comment: @muntoo, And to clear up something in the first one, they are treated as different types in that `void f(char);` and `void f(int);` are unambiguous, but with just one, it doesn't matter which you pass in.